# How to check if a file exists using wildcard chac in hadoop

Tags: shell, hadoop, hdfs

I am trying to check if the part-r files exist in Hadoop. Given below is the sample. The directories do not exist. I am trying to capture the return value and will be using that in a if-else condition to display message and proceed appropriately.

```
dir_1="/user/cloudera/asdf"
dir_2=${dir_1}"/part*"
dir_3="/user/cloudera/asdf/part-r-00000"
dir_4="/user/cloudera/asdf/part-r"

echo "Check 1. " ${dir_1}
hadoop fs -test -e ${dir_1}
retval=$?
echo "1. status is " $retval

echo "Check 2. " ${dir_2}
hadoop fs -test -e ${dir_2}
retval=$?
echo "2. status is " $retval


echo "Check 3. " ${dir_3}
hadoop fs -test -e ${dir_3}
retval=$?
echo "3. status is " $retval

echo "Check 4. " ${dir_1}/part*
hadoop fs -test -e ${dir_1}/part*
retval=$?
echo "4. status is " $retval

echo "Check 5. "
hadoop fs -ls ${dir_2}
retval=$?
echo "5. Status is " $retval
```

Output

```
[cloudera@quickstart cc_poc]$ sh chk.sh
Check 1.  /user/cloudera/asdf
1. status is  1
Check 2.  /user/cloudera/asdf/part*
test: `/user/cloudera/asdf/part*': No such file or directory
2. status is  1
Check 3.  /user/cloudera/asdf/part-r-00000
3. status is  1
Check 4.  /user/cloudera/asdf/part*
test: `/user/cloudera/asdf/part*': No such file or directory
4. status is  1
Check 5. 
ls: `/user/cloudera/asdf/part*': No such file or directory
5. Status is  1
```

If I use the directory or the filename fully, it returns only the return status. But if I try using * it displays an error.

My question 
1. Why the error message is not displayed for 1 & 3 (directory or full filename)
2. Is it possible to suppress the message and return the status alone for the others.

Comment: note: your dir_4 is never used. It go me confused

Comment: for more clarity, you could rename the check for what it does: test dir_1 ; test dir_2 ; test dir_3 ; test /user/cld/asdf/part* ; ls dir_2

Answer (score 0):

- For your 1st question: I'm not sure of what is intended but what can be observed is that hadoop print an error message when you pass it a path containing wildcard that doesn't exist. So, it needs both a wildcard and to not exist to produce the error message. In case of 1 and 3, the path doesn't exist but it doesn't contain a wildcard, do no error message
- For the 2nd question: you can redirect the error message (`hadoop .... 2>/dev/null`).

To conclude with the main question: "How to check if a file exists using wildcard char in hadoop", I simply `ls` with wildcard and count if it outputs something (also note the error redirection):

```
[ $(hdfs dfs -ls "/some/path/containing/*hello*" 2>/dev/null | wc -l) -ge 1 ] \
  && echo "file(s) exist" \
  || echo "no file found"
```